# How to clone a contentcontrol with storyboard animation (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, clone, contentcontrol

WPF .Net 4.5

> "'backgroundBrush' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid'."

I have a contentcontrol that is animating a path element by way of a storyboard. This works correctly in a side column, contained nicely in a StackPanel, on the right side of my display.

I would now like to drag-drop it onto an InkCanvas without removing it from its current position. Clearly, the WPF visual tree will not allow this so I need to clone it.

The best(?) method of cloning, (courtesy of StackOverflow), I could discover is:

```
 private void IC_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            InkCanvas ic = sender as InkCanvas;

            var ekg = e.Data.GetData("EKG") as ContentControl;
            if (ekg != null)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings
                {
                    Indent = true,
                    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
                    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
                    NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates,
                });
                var mgr = new XamlDesignerSerializationManager(writer);

                // HERE BE MAGIC!!!
                mgr.XamlWriterMode = XamlWriterMode.Expression;
                // THERE WERE MAGIC!!!

                XamlWriter.Save(ekg, mgr);

                StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
                XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
                ContentControl newECG = (ContentControl)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
                ic.Children.Add(newECG);
            }
}
```

However, doing so results in the above error.

How can this contentcontrol be cloned? Or failing cloning, is there a way to achieve the same effect of drag-dropping a path element with animation?

Here is the definition of ECG/EKG:

```
  <ContentControl Width="130" Height="130" PreviewMouseDown="ContentControl_PreviewMouseDown" >
            <ContentControl.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".4" ScaleY=".4"/>
            </ContentControl.LayoutTransform>

            <!--Must set IsHitTestVisible to True to allow tunneling/bubbeling of Mouse Events on the ContentControl.-->
            <Grid IsHitTestVisible="True">
                <!--FrameBackground is the gray background upon which the green oscilliscope is placed-->
                <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="#E0E0E0" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" Background="{DynamicResource FrameBackground}" />
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" CornerRadius="5" />
                <Border Background="{StaticResource MyGridBrushResource}" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5,5,5,25" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                <Border BorderBrush="#E0E0E0" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5,5,5,25"/>
                <Border BorderBrush="#303030" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5,5,5,25">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="Line">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Lime" />
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                            </Style>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="OnLoaded">
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1.0"
                               RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                               Duration="00:00:2"
                               Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundBrush"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="GradientStops[2].Offset">
                                </DoubleAnimation>

                                <DoubleAnimation From="0.01" To="1.01"
                               RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                               Duration="00:00:2"
                               Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundBrush"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty ="GradientStops[3].Offset">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation From="-0.9" To="0.1"
                               RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                               Duration="00:00:2"
                               Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundBrush"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty ="GradientStops[1].Offset">
                                </DoubleAnimation>

                            </Storyboard>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnLoaded}"/>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Grid.Triggers>

                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <Border BorderBrush="#00F300" BorderThickness="0" Margin="10">
                                <Path Name="polyLine" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill" Margin="5"
                    Data="M 0,10 4,10 6,8 7,10 9,10 10,11, 11,1 12,13 13,10 18,10 21,8 24,10
                            30,10 34,10 36,8 37,10 39,10 40,11, 41,1 42,13 43,10 48,10 51,8 54,10">
                                    <Path.Stroke>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="backgroundBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
                                            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset ="0.0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset ="0.0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#00FF00" Offset ="0.0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset ="0.0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset ="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Path.Stroke>
                                </Path>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ContentControl>
```

Any help or suggestions would be most appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

After much study and hair loss, no amount of re-styling, re-templating, or any other manuever would allow the XamlLWriter to copy the x:Name tags to the cloned control. Hence, the Storyboard animations could never find their targets. So the easiest solution (for me) was to make a content control out of the above. This allows drag-drop and addition to the InkCanvas without any problems.

```
<ContentControl
  x:Class="Doctor_Desk.Custom_Controls.EKGControl"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Doctor_Desk.Custom_Controls"
  x:Name="mainControl"
  >

    <ContentControl.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="DesignerItemStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        </Style>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="FrameBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="SlateGray" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="LightSlateGray" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <DrawingBrush x:Key="MyGridBrushResource"
                  Viewport="0,0,20,20"
                  ViewportUnits="Absolute"
                  TileMode="Tile">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L1,0 1,1 0,1z" Brush="#00AA00" />
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="DarkSlateGray">
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <GeometryGroup>
                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,0.01" />
                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0.01,0.01,1" />
                                </GeometryGroup>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </ContentControl.Resources>

        <ContentControl Width="130"
                      Height="130"
                      Padding="2"
                      Canvas.Left="380"
                      Canvas.Top="340"
                      Style="{StaticResource DesignerItemStyle}">

            <!--Must set IsHitTestVisible to "True" to enable PreviewMouseDown (or any Mouse Event)-->
        <Grid IsHitTestVisible="True">
            <Border CornerRadius="5"
                  BorderBrush="#E0E0E0"
                  BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"
                  Background="{DynamicResource FrameBackground}"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                  BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
                  CornerRadius="5" />
            <Border Background="{StaticResource MyGridBrushResource}" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5,5,5,25" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="#E0E0E0" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5,5,5,25"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="#303030" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5,5,5,25">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Line">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Lime" />
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                        </Style>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="OnLoaded">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1.0"
                                   RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                   Duration="00:00:2"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundBrush"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="GradientStops[2].Offset">
                            </DoubleAnimation>

                            <DoubleAnimation From="0.01" To="1.01"
                                   RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                   Duration="00:00:2"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundBrush"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty ="GradientStops[3].Offset">
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="-0.9" To="0.1"
                                   RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                   Duration="00:00:2"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundBrush"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty ="GradientStops[1].Offset">
                            </DoubleAnimation>

                        </Storyboard>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnLoaded}"/>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Grid.Triggers>
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Border BorderBrush="#00F300" BorderThickness="0" Margin="10">
                            <Path Name="polyLine" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill" Margin="5"
                        Data="M 0,10 4,10 6,8 7,10 9,10 10,11, 11,1 12,13 13,10 18,10 21,8 24,10
                                30,10 34,10 36,8 37,10 39,10 40,11, 41,1 42,13 43,10 48,10 51,8 54,10">
                                <Path.Stroke>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="backgroundBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
                                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset ="0.0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset ="0.0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00FF00" Offset ="0.0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset ="0.0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset ="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Stroke>
                            </Path>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ContentControl>

</ContentControl>
```